# Apache ant build failing in WSAD. 'package [com.company.myClass] does not exist"

Tags: java, apache, ant, wsad5.1

I have a new project that I'm trying to integrate with some existing functionality. In one of my old services I've include some initialization for the new classes and I used the "Organize Imports" feature to find and import the packages automatically. When I try to package the class with Apache Ant the build fails with errors saying that the packages don't exist. I've added the new project to the build path and double checked the package names. What could still be preventing the app from picking up the new project?

Using:
WebSphere Studio Application Developer version 5.1.2
WebSphere v5.1 JRE
Apache Ant 1.6.2

EDIT:
I re-ran ant with the -v argument (by the way light green text in the white console output is a recipe for eye-strain) and it turns out the package/project isn't showing up. I modified the properties to include the package so I don't know why it wouldn't show up, but that is definitely the issue. I hope that sheds some light.

EDIT: SOLVED:
Alright I feel foolish. The build ran this time. I opened build_new.xml and added "include name="[myClass].jar" />" to the path section under "fileset dir="${global.module.dir}">". There are other problems with other projects to deal with so I'm not sure if that fixed all the related issues but the build succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

So from your post I can understand that you have added a dependency from one of your old project to the new project. If this is the case then please make sure that the old project is getting compiled after the new one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. It's good advice, but I already thought of that. The new project compiles just fine unfortunately the same can't be said for the old one.

Comment: Well the only reasons I can imagine is that the jar of new project is not present in the same dest or lib directory while compiling the other project.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You definitely were on the right track.